# Chaining two $http calls and returning the result of the second

Tags: angularjs

I have an *Angular Service* that I'd like to use to perform two `$http` calls, and return the result of the second. Here's the service:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .service('farm', ['$http']);

function farm($http) {
  this.saveFruit = function(fruit) {
    return $http.get('http://example.com/get-token').success(function(token) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://example.com/save-fruit',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': token },
            data: { fruit: fruit }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

At this point, the code works fine. I'm able to "save some fruit", which grabs a token for itself via `GET`, then sends the data via `POST`, and everything is saved up in the cloud, great.

To call this service, I'm using code like this:

```
var fruit = { name: 'Apple', color: 'red' };
farm.saveFruit(fruit).success(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

However, the `console.log()` always prints out the result of the `$http` **GET**, instead of the ***POST***.

How do I get the result of the `$http` **POST** call when calling `saveFruit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`success()` doesn't allow chaining promises. Use the real thing: `then()`.

```
return $http.get('http://example.com/get-token').then(function(response) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/save-fruit',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': response.data },
    data: { fruit: fruit }
  });
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});
```

and

```
var fruit = { name: 'Apple', color: 'red' };
farm.saveFruit(fruit).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `.success` and `.error` methods of `$http` breaks the promise chain. This is undocumented and could be considered a bug.

In order to continue the promise chain, use `.then` (and `.catch`, as needed).

```
return $http.get('http://example.com/get-token').then(function(response) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/save-fruit',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': response.data },
        data: { fruit: fruit }
    });
});
```